# Removing toprule from Table created using kableExtra not working

Tags: r, latex, tex, kable, kableextra

I've created a table using kable/kableExtra. This is the code:

```
library(kableExtra)

tbl_img <- data.frame(
name = c("kableExtra 1"),
logo = ""
)
tbl_img %>%
  kbl(booktabs = TRUE, col.names = NULL, valign = "t", linesep = "", toprule = FALSE) %>%
    kable_paper(full_width = T) %>%
    column_spec(2, image = "images/square.png")
```

But it keeps giving me this error:

> Error in if (bold) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Error appears when I try to add toprule attribute. Basically, I don't want top and bottom lines on my table. What am I doing wrong?